# How to run MPI program on multiple machines on windows?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am going to do some parallel computing and I'm totally a beginner in this area. I will use MPI to do the parallel work, with Master-Slave model. I now have two machines with microsoft sdk installed and want one of them to be the Master Node. However, I don't know how to specify the other machines running the program. Is there a way like specifying the IP address of slave node? How to launch my program?

Answer (score 1):

Any answer depends on your MPI implementation.  You can find several for windows, including Intel-MPI and MS-MPI.

Let's start with MS-MPI since it's freely available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Then, the guide here should get you pretty far:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2539.diy-supercomputing-how-to-build-a-small-windows-hpc-cluster.aspx